# Valgrind reports different numbers of allocs and frees, yet all blocks freed

Tags: c, fortran, mpi, valgrind, heap-memory

I run an executable with `valgrind`. The executable is written in C and calls a large numerical C library which includes Fortran code and uses MPI (MPICH).

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./ex1
==13877== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13877== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13877== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13877== Command: ./ex1
==13877== 
==13877== 
==13877== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13877==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13877==   total heap usage: 2,057 allocs, 2,046 frees, 4,812,368 bytes allocated
==13877== 
==13877== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13877== 
==13877== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13877== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Note that in the heap summary, there are more allocs than frees, yet no leaks (not even "still reachable" ones) are reported. I don't understand how this is possible. **Is this inconsistent output, or is there a legitimate mechanism which could produce this?**

Running with `-v` gives output including this warning:

```
==14266== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
--14266--     old: 0x0401f2f0 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x58060901 ???
--14266--     new: 0x0401f2f0 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c32db0 strlen
```

Comment: Maybe `realloc()` counts as one alloc (and your run had 11 reallocs)?

Comment: That's not what I would expect, naively. This, shows 2 allocs and 2 frees: `printf "#include <stdlib.h>\n int main(){int* a = malloc(10); int* b = realloc(a,20); free(b);}" > t.c && gcc -O0 t.c && valgrind ./a.out`

Comment: How is this question related to MPI?

Comment: It's running a code which depends on MPI, so conceivably the MPI implementation could be involved in this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, this appears to be an issue with the MPI implementation, MPICH, which [provides custom logic to valgrind](https://wiki.mpich.org/mpich/index.php/Support_for_Debugging_Memory_Allocation#Valgrind_Integration), as it uses nonstandard heap allocation procedures.

In particular, the problem can be reproduced with a simple MPI program.

```
#include <mpi.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

```
==7291== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7291== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7291== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7291== Command: ./a.out
==7291==
==7291==
==7291== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7291==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7291==   total heap usage: 1,979 allocs, 1,974 frees, 4,720,483 bytes allocated
==7291==
==7291== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7291==
==7291== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7291== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

This is using MPICH 3.1b1, configured with

```
$ ./configure --prefix=[REMOVED] MAKE=/usr/bin/make --libdir=[REMOVED] CC=gcc CFLAGS=-fPIC -fstack-protector -g -O3 AR=/usr/bin/ar ARFLAGS=cr CXX=g++ CXXFLAGS=-fstack-protector -g -O3 -fPIC F77=gfortran FFLAGS=-fPIC -ffree-line-length-0 -g -O3 FC=gfortran FCFLAGS=-fPIC -ffree-line-length-0 -g -O3 --enable-shared --with-device=ch3:sock --with-pm=hydra --enable-g=meminit
```